# Android Listview mixed up items

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView, with a custom item.

The item's layout:

I have the following to classes for storing the informations:

```
public class MainItem{

private int DrawableId;
private String title;

public  MainItem(String title, int drawable)
{
    this.title = title;
    this.DrawableId = drawable;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public int getDrawableId() {
    return DrawableId;
}}
```

and

```
public class MainRow{

public MainItem getMainItem1() {
    return mainItem1;
}

public MainItem getMainItem2() {
    return mainItem2;
}

public MainItem getMainItem3() {
    return mainItem3;
}
```

private  MainItem mainItem1, mainItem2, mainItem3;

```
public int getNumberOfItems() {
    return numberOfItems;
}
```

private int numberOfItems = 0;

```
public MainRow(MainItem mainItem)
{
    this(1,mainItem,null,null);
}

public MainRow(MainItem mainItem, MainItem mitem2)
{
    this(2,mainItem,mitem2,null);
}
public MainRow(int nb, MainItem mainItem, MainItem mainItem2, MainItem mainItem3)
{
    this.mainItem1 = mainItem;
    this.mainItem2 = mainItem2;
    this.mainItem3 = mainItem3;
    this.numberOfItems = nb;
}}
```

and finnaly my BaseAdapter is :

```
public class MainItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

List<MainRow> mitems;
```

MainScreenItemLisener mainScreenItemLisener;

```
    public MainItemAdapter(MainScreenItemLisener mainScreenItemLisener, ArrayList<MainRow> list)
    {
        mitems = list;
        this.mainScreenItemLisener = mainScreenItemLisener;
    }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mitems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mitems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgLeft, imgRight, imgMiddle;
    TextView tvLeft, tvRight, tvMiddle;
    LinearLayout mLeft, mRight, mMiddle;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder = null;


    if (convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_screen_two, null);
           holder.imgLeft = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_left);
        holder.imgMiddle = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_middle);
            holder.imgRight = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_right);
            holder.tvLeft = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvLeft);
            holder.tvRight = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvRight);
             holder.tvMiddle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMiddle);
            holder.mLeft = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mLinearLauoutleft);
            holder.mRight = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mLinearLauoutRight);
        holder.mMiddle = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mLinearLauoutMiddle);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final MainRow mItem = mitems.get(position);

    if(mItem.getNumberOfItems() >=1)
    if(mItem.getMainItem1() != null)
    {

        Picasso.with(parent.getContext())
                  .load(mItem.getMainItem1().getDrawableId())
                    .into( holder.imgLeft);
            holder.tvLeft.setText(mItem.getMainItem1().getTitle());

          holder.mLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
             mainScreenItemLisener.ItemClicked(mItem.getMainItem1());     }
          });

    }

    if(mItem.getNumberOfItems() ==1) return convertView;

    if(mItem.getNumberOfItems() >=2)
    if(mItem.getMainItem2() != null)
    {

        Picasso.with(parent.getContext())
                .load(mItem.getMainItem2().getDrawableId())
                .into( holder.imgMiddle);
        holder.tvMiddle.setText(mItem.getMainItem2().getTitle());

        holder.mMiddle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mainScreenItemLisener.ItemClicked(mItem.getMainItem2());}
        });
    }

    if(mItem.getNumberOfItems() >=3)
    if(mItem.getMainItem3() != null)
    {

        Picasso.with(parent.getContext())
                .load(mItem.getMainItem3().getDrawableId())
                .into( holder.imgRight);
        holder.tvRight.setText(mItem.getMainItem3().getTitle());

        holder.mRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mainScreenItemLisener.ItemClicked(mItem.getMainItem3());}
        });
    }
    return convertView;
}}
```

My problem is the following:

When the listview is firstly created is shown as in the following image:

The setup :

```
items.add(new MainRow(3, new MainItem(getString(R.string.evenimente),R.drawable.evenimente),
                            new MainItem(getString(R.string.atracti_turistice),R.drawable.atracti_turistice),
                            new MainItem(getString(R.string.ture_turistice), R.drawable.ghid)));

    items.add(new MainRow(3, new MainItem(getString(R.string.restaurante),R.drawable.restaurant),
                              new MainItem(getString(R.string.hoteluri),R.drawable.hotel),
                               new MainItem(getString(R.string.spa), R.drawable.spa_wellnes)));

    items.add(new MainRow(3, new MainItem(getString(R.string.nightlife),R.drawable.clubs),
                              new MainItem(getString(R.string.shopping),R.drawable.shop),
                              new MainItem(getString(R.string.transport_local), R.drawable.transport)));


    items.add(new MainRow(3, new MainItem(getString(R.string.parcari),R.drawable.parcari),
                               new MainItem(getString(R.string.servicii_medicale),R.drawable.service_medicale),
                            new MainItem(getString(R.string.service_auto), R.drawable.service_auto)));


    items.add(new MainRow(new MainItem(getString(R.string.map),R.drawable.harta)));

    mainItemAdapter = new MainItemAdapter(this,items);

    mListView.setAdapter(mainItemAdapter);
```

In the last row only the "Altele" stuff is puted, but when the listview is shown at the first time, as how you see there is something from another item in plus. What to do ?

[image: This is how it looks like!]

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just use a GridView to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an "else" case in your if-logic.  You must explicitly set each row because the rows are being re-used.  Also, if-logic without curly-braces is bad mojo and made your getView() difficult to follow.

For instance, what if your last row does not have 3 items?  The following 2 slots will get re-used and display the images that were previously in those rows.  This line `if(mItem.getNumberOfItems() ==1) return convertView;`
 is your culprit.

Now ... you're code (updated):

```
if(mItem.getNumberOfItems() >=2) {
    if(mItem.getMainItem2() != null) {
        // do something
    }
}

// OR

if(mItem.getNumberOfItems() >=2 && mItem.getMainItem2() != null) {
        // do something
}
```